# Написание Windows Form Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Добрый день!

Нужно написать программу, именно с окошками. Программа должна уметь

1. Открывать файл (без опенфайл диалога), читать оттуда текст, выводить на экран.
2. Параллельно, эта же программа должна не подвисая отправлять по протоколу tcp сообщения.

Своего рода аська. Как в консоли открывать файл я знаю, а как быть тут?(файл один и тот же) В FA есть непонятный мне systemstring. Его нужно в char для open преобразовывать? Может есть более элегантный способ открытия файла на чтение и запись? Как в виндовс создать процесс я не понял, windowsprocesscreate не пошел. В линуксе было всё просто. Есть ли в винде аналог fork()?

Спасибо.

Comment: а что такое "windows FA"?

Comment: Windows Form Application

Comment: Аналога fork в виндах нет (есть эмуляции cygwin/u-win, но здесь это не подходит). Есть CreateProcess, но более естественным для win является создание нитей/потоков CreateThread.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду [WinForms](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)? (Если да, почему тогда C++?)

Answer (score 1):

```
1) ofstream + ifstream из стандартной библиотеки  + mfc (windows.h) для вывода на экран.
2) winsock
```

Comment: А winsock не подвесит всё при ожидании соединения?

Comment: если прямое соединение между двумя компами без авторизации то думаю что не подвесит. соединение то всего один раз надо будет сделать (пока форма открыта)

Comment: хотите, что бы не подвешивало - используйте потоки.

Comment: Можете нормальную, четкую ссылку про потоки в windows дать?

Comment: Если задача учебная и без претензий к производительности, а данные, отправляемые по tcp -- копия вывода на экран, то достаточно цикла.